# find and replace keywords with urls ONLY if not already wrapped in a url

Tags: php

So, I can easily do this:

```
$keywords = array(' jacket ',' sweater ',);
$urls = array(' <a href="#">jacket</a> ',' <a href="#">sweater</a> ',);
$content = str_ireplace($keywords,$urls,$content);
```

But the problem is when something like jacket or sweater is already in a link tag.

I can't think of any simple solutions to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- step 1) find all instances of each
  keyword which are within a url &
  replace them with a GUID
- step 2) replace all other instances of each
  keyword with thier replacement
- step 3) replace the GUID's with their
  origional keywords.

Hope you choose your Guid's and how you do your searching is up to you :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this a bit later, I'll update this post if I get something functional...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to construct a fancy regex for this, but it would be extremely complicated and nearly impossible to maintain. IMO, you should take a token-based approach to solve this problem. I have a project called [Lexentity](https://github.com/scoates/lexentity) that we use to replace apostrophes and quotes, etc., with their numerical entities. You could probably adapt that code for your purposes. There's also a [HTMLTokenizer](https://trac.habariproject.org/habari/browser/trunk/htdocs/system/classes/htmltokenizer.php) (and [HTMLTokenset](https://trac.habariproject.org/habari/browser/trunk/htdocs/system/classes/htmltokenset.php)) in [Habari](http://habariproject.org/) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check it out.