# Python String Replace: Keywords into URLs

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine, utf-8

I am going to replace some keywords with urls in a string, for example,

```
content.replace("Google","<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>")
```

However, I only want to replace keywords with urls ONLY if not already wrapped in a url.

The content is simple HTML:

```
<p><b>This is an example!</b></p><p>I love <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p><p><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="/google.jpg" /></a></p>
```

Mainly `<a>` and `<img>` tags.

**The main question: How to determine if a keyword is already wrapped in a `<a>` or `<img>` tag?**

Here is a similar question in PHP [find and replace keywords with urls ONLY if not already wrapped in a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522143/find-and-replace-keywords-with-urls-only-if-not-already-wrapped-in-a-url), but the answer is not an efficient one.

Is there some better solutions in Python? Better with code examples. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of text you want want to run this function on?

Comment: @Acorn HTML web page. Example: `<p><b>This is an example!</b></p><p>I love <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p><p><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="/google.jpg" /></a></p>`

Comment: You can use the example I have shown below to create a regular expression that matches that with <a> or <img> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris-Top said, BeautifulSoup is the way to go:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString
import re    

html = """
<div>
    <p>The quick brown <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog'>fox</a> jumped over the lazy Dog</p>
    <p>The <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog'>dog</a>, who was, in reality, not so lazy, gave chase to the fox.</p>
    <p>See image for reference:</p>
    <img src='dog_chasing_fox.jpg' title='Dog chasing fox'/>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#search term, url reference
keywords = [("dog","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog"),
            ("fox","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox")]

def insertLinks(string_value,string_href):
    for t in soup.findAll(text=re.compile(string_value, re.IGNORECASE)):
            if t.parent.name !='a':
                    a = Tag('a', name='a')
                    a['href'] = string_href
                    a.insert(0, NavigableString(string_value))
                    string_list = re.compile(string_value, re.IGNORECASE).split(t)
                    replacement_text = soup.new_string(string_list[0])
                    t.replace_with(replacement_text)
                    replacement_text.insert_after(a)
                    a.insert_after(soup.new_string(string_list[1]))


for word in keywords:
    insertLinks(word[0],word[1])

print soup
```

Will yield:

```
<div>
    <p>The quick brown <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog">fox</a> jumped over the lazy <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog">dog</a></p>
    <p>The <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog">dog</a>, who was, in reality, not so lazy, gave chase to the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox">fox</a>.</p>
    <p>See image for reference:</p>
    <img src="dog_chasing_fox.jpg" title="Dog chasing fox"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this entire time I was trying to solve the problem using the HTMLParser library... I was working on it for like 3 hours... And then there was a library already made for it :(

Comment: @Kevin P thanks for putting the time to submit some working code :)

Answer (score 4):

I am using [Beatiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing my HTML, since [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) HTML with regex can..be proven tricky. If you use beautiful soup you can toy with [previous_sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) and previous_element figure out what you need.

You interact in this fashion:

```
soup.find_all('img')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a regular expression as mentioned in the previous post. First check your string against a regular expression to check whether it has already been wrapped in a URL. This should be pretty easy as a simple call to the re library and its search() method should do the trick.

Here is a nice tutorial if you need for regular expressions and the search method specifically: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

After you check the string to see whether it is already wrapped in a URL or not, you can call the replace function if it is not already wrapped in a URL.

Here is a quick example that I wrote:

```
    import re

    x = "<a href=""http://www.google.com"">Google</a>"
    y = 'Google'

    def checkURL(string):
        if re.search(r'<a href.+', string):
            print "URL Wrapped Already"
            print string
        else:
            string = string.replace('Google', "<a href=""http://www.google.com"">Google</a>")
            print "URL Not Wrapped:"
            print string

    checkURL(x)
    checkURL(y)
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Huh? I dont seem to get you. I am not searching for a specific string. I want to replace keywords with urls ONLY if not already wrapped in a url.

Comment: Can you give an example of text that you may use?